# Visual Studio 2022 still looking for v142 platform toolset

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I've recently replaced Visual Studio 2019 with Visual Studio 2022 as my team recantly introduced support for it.

I'm now facing a strange error when building the following project specification with Visual Studio 2022:
[image: Project Configuration Debug Unicode]
Error:

```
MSB8020 The build tools for Visual Studio 2019 (Platform Toolset = 'v142') cannot be found.
To build using the v142 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2019 build tools.
Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project
menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".
```

I've tried to retarget the project several times, the strage think is that with the "Debug" configuration (apparently idantical regarding toolset) the project just builds fine:
[image: Project Configuration Debug]

Is there any other setting I may be missing in order to completely port my project to the 143 platform toolset?

Thanks

Comment: This project has non-standard configurations and none of the screenshots show the active configuration and platform.  So good odds that you haven't yet seen the toolset being set wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've been able to understand what was wrong.
The projects were updated to v143 in a manual way using a text editor: the main project references other projects and the references were not updated so when building the main project Visual Studio still tried to build the old project designed for Visual Studio 2019.
Once I've updated the references to the new projects for Visual Studio 2022 everything builds fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to open the project file in a text editor, search for occurences of

```
 <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
```

and replace them by v143 (or use the information where you found it to identify the configuration which causes the issue). You may also replace

```
 <VCToolsVersion>"some specific version number"</VCToolsVersion>
```

by

```
 <VCToolsVersion></VCToolsVersion>
```

Comment: I've tried with a text editor but I can't find any instance of:
` <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>`
What I can find is just:
` <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>`

Comment: @ss900ie: maybe you need to remove the specific version from the <VCToolsVersion> element as well (we did so when we switched to v143).